# .NET: Is it OK to use async/await in classic threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await

I'm using "classic" threads to run multiple independent workloads in parallel.

Threads are started like this:

```cs
var thread = new Thread(() => ThreadFunc(somecontextvariable));
thread.Start();
```

Inside `ThreadFunc` I'm using `async/await`. `ThreadFunc`'s return signature is `async void`. Multiple of those threads are running in parallel.

Is that OK from an `async/await` standpoint? Or am I in for trouble? I'm asking because I sometimes see deadlock-like behavior when exceptions are thrown (and handled) inside those threads and I'm not sure how to interpret this.

So, questioning everything, I'm starting with this question: Is it OK to use "classic" threads with `async void` thread funcs that use `async/await` in their bodies?

Comment: Using some `[async] void` method as an ultimate entry point for async-await operations is quite common in certain cases (and not just for events) so this is not a problem in itself. You just need to be able to handle the fire-and-forget nature of async void at the root level. And actually you can expose also such solutions as regular awaitable tasks by using a `TaskCompletionSource`. Of course, this has some pitfalls as you must ensure that the task is completed in every circumstances; otherwise, a caller may stuck at awaiting your custom task forever.

Comment: Is your intention to run the `ThreadFunc` on the specific `Thread` from start to finish? Also have you considered invoking your `async void` method on the `ThreadPool` instead of using dedicated threads? `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => ThreadFunc(x));`

Comment: *"I sometimes see deadlock-like behavior when exceptions are thrown (and handled) inside those threads"* -- Could you provide a minimal demo that reproduces the deadlock-like behavior?

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg you could consider posting [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75571281/net-is-it-ok-to-use-async-await-in-classic-threads#comment133328254_75571281) as an answer. Comments are intended for clarifying the question, not answering it.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias: you are correct, though in this case I thought this would've been too vague as an answer because many details are not known.

Comment: @GyörgyKőszeg we should focus on clarifying these unknown details then!

Comment: I'm not able to provide details because I don't know any yet. It seems like there is a chain of "Thread -> async/await -> ReactiveExtensions Observables with async/await" where throwing an exception messes up something. So I thought that I should first question my premise that doing async/await from threads is OK in principle. The answers so far suggest that it is. The answer by @guru-stron goes a step further and makes me over-think starting threads at all because everything will be on the thread pool anyway. Thanks for all your input!

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that using `Thread`'s with async-await usually is rather pointless. Even if your method was `async Task` (which it should, by the way, you should [avoid `async void`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming#avoid-async-void) when it is possible) the thread's are not `Task`-ware. If your method is actually async and does not perform any CPU-intensive work before `await` using `new Thread(() => SomeAsync())` will actually just create a throw-away thread to schedule the continuation on the thread pool. The only difference compared to just invoking the method would capturing the synchronization context but better approach would be using `Task.Run(() => ...)`.

> I'm asking because I sometimes see deadlock-like behavior when exceptions are thrown (and handled) inside those threads and I'm not sure how to interpret this.

AFAIK there is no additional reasons for deadlocks here, sounds like the method itself (if anything) has some deadlock issues in case of exceptions.